# Create Array from another Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an array that looks like this:

```
(
        {
        title = "Chris";
        isMale = 1;
        age = 13;
    },
        {
        defaultTitle = "Jessica";
        isMale = 0;
        age = 15;
    }
)
```

I want to create another array that contains the dictionaries from the original array where the BOOL `isMale` is Yes, or `1`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a predicate. You can filter an array with the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [originalAray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isMale == %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]];
```